# How do I change the format of a specific column in EPPlus?

Tags: asp.net, excel, epplus

I've used EPPlus to download my datatable from my website / database to an Excel sheet and the first picture is the result I get. The second picture is what I would like it to be.

**Questions:**

- **How do I change the format of my Timestamp to "time"?**

Obviously title would still be a string format.

- **How do I make the width of the columns to match the longest word inside?**

So that 80% of the message isn't hidden and you have to drag the column out to read the entire message.

### Edit: Completely forgot to add my code...

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            DataTable dataTable = GetData();

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
                //true generates headers
                ws.Cells["1:1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
                ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                package.SaveAs(stream);

                string fileName = "Log.xlsx";
                string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

                stream.Position = 0;
                return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
            }
        }

        public DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", Session["myID"]);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", "%" + Session["mySearchString"] + "%");
                        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Log WHERE CustomerId = @val1 AND Message LIKE @val2";
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
                        }
                        catch (SqlException e)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(e.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: To fit the column width you can use following line of code. worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

Comment: @KeerthiKumar thank you, it worked. ½ way done! :)

Comment: Flag for what? @KeerthiKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to set the `Numberformat.Format` string.  Like this:

```
ws.Column(2).Style.Numberformat.Format = "hh:mm:ss";
```

If you want to customize the actual just there are plenty of resource online like http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-custom-number-formats.htm.  Or you can just open it in excel, set the format to `Custom` and experiment with the string.

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to add code to my post. If possible, could you tailor the answer to the code given? Or just have the line needed and I will mark as an answer.